# NSNumberFormatter Problem

Tags: iphone, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

IN my App i have to share the amount among the event people for Example  i have 3 people names like RAM, RAJ, RAGHU ,if RAM put amount of 10.00 in event than i am dividing the among three people like `10.00/3=3.333333`, Then,

> RAJ has to pay to RAM-------------3.33
>   RAGHU has to pay to RAM -------3.33

over all he getting From other 2 people in the event 6.66
here 0.1 missing how can i solve this problem 
i  am using  NumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle like below

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormater = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormater setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[numberFormater setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *str_num = [numberFormater stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:3.333333]];
[numberFormater release];
```

Comment: how can i divide the 10.00 among three people

Comment: since the smallest is .01 then I would add .01 for each person before dividing it. so if it is 5 people add .05 then RAM will never be short changed the bill will get paid and not one would pay more than a cent extra. ( for 3 people ad .03. etc)

Comment: RAM only pay 10.00 only for that event how can add 0.03 to that amont

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you subtract RAM's share from 10? 10 - 3.33 = 6.67.

Comment: Not really. .9999... = 1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999... You need to define your precision digits & then round -up/down. They are paying 3.33333..... each, which multiplied by 3 is equal to 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
  float invoice= 10.15;
  int num_people = 3; // sample people
  float num_to_add;
  float piece_pie;
  // now just add num_to_add to your invoice then divide by num_people
  num_to_add=num_people*.01;
  invoice=invoice+num_to_add;
  piece_pie = invoice/num_people;
```